# How can I express a tensor in terms of a basis different to canonical?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensor-decomposition

Considerthe canonical basis $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$  and its dual basis $e^1 , e^2 , e^3$. Let $A = (a_{ij})$ a matrix in $M_{3 \times 3}(\mathbb{R})$ given by:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -3  & 1\\
-3 & -3 & 3\\
1 & 3 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
Now consider the following basis of eigen vectors $f_1,f_2,f_3$ from $A$ each of them given, explicitly by:
$$B = \{(1,0,1),(1,-1,-1),(1,2,-1)\}$$
and its dual basis $(f^1,f^2,f^3)$.

I have the following $(0,2)$-tensor:
$$s(x^i e_i,y^i e_i) = a_{ij}x^{i}y^{j}$$
How can I write the same tensor but as a linear combination of tesonsotrial products between the elements of $(f^1,f^2,f^3)$ basis?
For instance I know that $s$ in terms of canonical basis could be expreed as:
$$s(x^i e_i,y^i e_i) = a_{ij}(e^i \otimes e^j)(x^i e_i,y^i e_i)$$
My question is what should I put as $\star$ such that the following becomes true:
$$s(x^i f_i,y^i f_i) = \star(f^i \otimes f^j)(x^i f_i,y^i f_i)$$

Comment: Did you mean to write
$$
s(x^i f_i,y^i f_i) = \star(f^i \otimes f^j)(x^i f_i,y^i f_i)?
$$

Comment: Yes @BenGrossmann